# JMeter Exception thrown by org.apache.jmeter.util.HostNameSetter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm facing a weird issue. I created a JMeter script and I was able to run it from GUI interface, but when I try to run it by command line I get this failure message:

> An illegal reflective access operation has occured.
>
> Illegal reflective access by org.apache.jmeter.util.HostNameSetter ... to method sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setHost(java.lang.String)
>   ...
>
> Uncaught Exception java.lang.StackOverFlowError

I can't figure out why the script (running via VPN on Stage environment) is able to run from GUI and it fails when is launched from command line instead.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most on-topic question I've seen for long...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use java 8 or 9 for your test, but Java8 is advised.

Show jmeter.log if issue persists after using Java8 .